# Share image, but no file extension

Tags: android, image, share

I want to share a image that is in my own application and I do so with the following code:

```
Intent shareIntent =  new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://"package"/drawable/" + card_name));
shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_app_via)));
```

Far without problems,  but if I send the image to the email and download it, the image has no extension.jpg and therefore can not be opened.

How I can do to put jpg extension to image?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting  .jpg at the end of card_name

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://"package"/drawable/" + card_name + ".jpg"));
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried. If I put +".jpg" does not send anything because there is no image in the folder drawable. That is not recognized as a .jpg extension but as a name.